# ASP.Net Bearer Authentication using JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I have implemented the normal login behavior where a JWT token is issued upon successful logon. The API (ASP.Net) should then restrict access to certain Controller actions using the `[Authorize]` attribute - however I keep on getting a:

> 401 - Unauthorized response ("Authorization has been denied for this request.")

I am relatively sure I am not configuring the JWT Token authentication correctly - however I have this in my startup, using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
}

private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {
            AllowedAudiences = new string[] { "*" },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "SomeValidIssuer",

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "SomeValidAudience",

                ValidateLifetime = true,

                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysupersecretkey"))
            }
        }
    );
}
```

With a very simple token being passed through to the request via header:

> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzM1NzY5MDEsImlzcyI6IlNvbWVWYWxpZElzc3VlciIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbWVWYWxpZEF1ZGllbmNlIn0.YfgbVuLgjTagkZTHwXRh9gQxOq5boeMa7TOgq0keKc0

You can use [this](http://jwt.io) site to see the contents of the token

I have followed [this](https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/) excellent link on Securing your ASP.NET Core 2.0 API which is working like a charm, but dotNetCore is not an option for the project I am currently working on - however I have followed a similar path in issuing the tokens.

What am I doing wrong, why am I getting a 401 on my request?

Comment: Check your network tab and confirm passing token into the header

Comment: The token is definitely in there. I'm also using postman to test, and the token is definitely there

Comment: If postman request success then it might be your token is undefine from your client.

Comment: No the token is generated and sent through the header from the client. The problem is that the webAPI does not know what to validate the incoming token against - what audiences/issuers are valid? What key should be used? I have found an answer and will post it later when I have access to the project.